# iPad & iPhone orientation: when I click my second view and rotate and then switch back to the first view my controls are not repositioned

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xcode4

I have an app for the iPad/iPhone and Portrait and Landscape is working just fine.  However, I recently added a TabViewController and a second tab with a view.  Problem is when I click my second view and rotate and then switch back to the first view my controls are not repositioned

Can anyone tell me what I need to do so that I can reposition my views when the first view is clicked?

incidentally, I am assuming I will have the same problem the other way too... view 2 to view 1.

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked that all your view controller implement this method ?

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Comment: @Tony - yes you should implement this delegate in all of your view contorllers.

Comment: Yes.  Like I said, everything was fine until I added the TabViewController and a second view.  I am assuming I need to respond to an event that tells me it was rotated so that I can run my re-position code to move the controls to the new location based on the orientation.  Currently I move my controls from this: - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation    duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

Comment: Ok, I amnew to iPad development and I sort of understand that, but could you give me a little bit more detail.  I THINK I now what you mean by, "implement this delegate into all of your view controllers" but more detail would be helpful.

Comment: @Tony It mean that all your view controller should have this method present in their code. If you have 4 tab, try to "implement"/write this method in each of 4 view controller. Hope you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the same problem also occurs with navigation controller. I guess that the framework wont send the rotation event to every hidden VC on purpose to save processing time. The solution I ever did is just overriding `viewWillAppear` and correctly layout subviews there if needed.